# S3 static web hosting page redirect to reset password page

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3

I have a static website hosted on S3. My application is sending a mail with a link to reset a password. When I click I should see reset password page. But this is not happening and it shows "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)".

How can I make my application redirect to reset password page when the user clicks on the reset password link sent in the mail?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your file/page is marked as public in S3 and there is not ACL / Bucket Policy denying the access for the same

https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/